# Java HTMLUnit - How do I access the page DOM I'm sent to after submitting a form

Tags: java, html, htmlunit

I'm very confused on how to access the newly loaded page's DOM after I .click() the submit button on a page and am sent to another one.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The click() method should return an HtmlPage object with the new page:

```
HtmlPage newPage = myElement.click();
```

Comment: Haven't tested it, but it makes sense to me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're being redirected to a new page, wouldn't you handle that page's DOM just like you normally would? In jQuery you would use:

[`$(document).ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

And when the DOM has finished loading, you can manipulate it however you want.